# Cannot initiate the connection to repo.mongodb.org:443

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I'm following Microsoft's official documentation to install MongoDB in WSL 2.
When I reached the 5th step it returns some error. The step was Reload local package database: `sudo apt-get update`

Here is the sort form of the error,

```
Err:1 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to repo.mongodb.org:443 (2600:9000:213a:6a00:1e:e933:9800:93a1). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to repo.mongodb.org:443 (2600:9000:213a:6400:1e:e933:9800:93a1). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to repo.mongodb.org:443 (2600:9000:213a:f200:1e:e933:9800:93a1).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSL2 [doesn't support routing IPv6](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4518), and for some reason apt is trying to connect to `repo.mongodb.org` using IPv6.

Try:

```
sudo apt update -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true
```

This is a workaround (if it works).  You may run into other issues with IPv6, and if so, check out [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1200257/1165986) and see if that helps.

Comment: has same issue inside Ubuntu 22.04 container and tried the workaround . Still getting the error